# Renaming files with the same name using sequential numbers?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I feel like this is pretty simple, but I'm missing something. I have 130 folders, all containing the same file, "Document.pdf". Of course, the contents vary from file to file, but they all have the same name and extension. What I'm trying to do is have a script take all those 130 files, and give them names from "1.pdf" to "130.pdf", in order. The folders are in order as well (1-130). I have these folders on both local storage and Google Drive, so any solution involving either bash or GScripts will be good with me. Thanks.

Comment: Are the folders named `1`, `2`, and so on up to `130`?

Comment: `The folders are in order as well` what order? alphabetical, order based on the name? order based on when they were created? provide more details

Comment: Details are pretty much vague at this point so I did some assumptions on my answer below. Kindly check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

#### Code:

```
function renameFiles() {
  var iter = 1;
  while (iter <= 130) {
    Logger.log(iter);
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(iter);
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
      var folder = folders.next();
      Logger.log("Folder: " + folder.getName());
      var files = folder.getFilesByName("Document.pdf");
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        file.setName(iter + "." + file.getMimeType().substr(-3));
        Logger.log("File: " + file.getName());
      }
    }
    iter++;
  }
}
```

#### Assumptions:

- Folders are named `1`, `2`, .... `130`

#### Sample ouptut:

[image: output]

Comment: That looks great. The only issue on my side is that "Document.pdf" isn't the only file in the folder, so I need it to target "Document.pdf" instead of doing .getFiles() generically. However, your solution does answer what I asked, so thank you!

Comment: If that's the case @chuckster1, I have updated my answer. You only need to use `var files = folder.getFilesByName("Document.pdf");` instead of `var files = folder.getFiles();` and it should work. If your question was solved, please push the accept button. Other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I also moved the `iter++` due to issues with the absence of the file being renamed. @chuckster1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the directories are actually named `1`, `2`, and so on up to and including `130`, here is a bash solution:

```sh
# Edit this to desired path
parent_dir='.'

find "$parent_dir" -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read -r directory; do
    dir_name="$(basename directory)"

    if [ "$dir_name" -ge 1 ] && [ "$dir_name" -le 130 ]; then
        mv "$directory/Document.pdf" "$directory/$dir_name.pdf"
    fi
done
```

This uses `basename` to get the name of each directory (i.e., the value between 1 and 130), and uses that to rename the `Document.pdf` files.

Note that `-maxdepth` is not POSIX. To replace `-maxdepth` with POSIX options, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330372/392334).

Comment: Very unique way in using the folder name instead of using an iterator.

Comment: This looks like it will work perfectly. I'll try both yours and @NaziA solution soon.